# When are the points of intersection of two real affine conics orthogonal to each other?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Show that the lines joining the origin to the points of intersection of two curves $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx=0$ and $a_1x^2+2h_1xy+b_1y^2+2g_1x=0$ will be at right angles to one another if $g(a_1+b_1)=g_1(a+b)$.

My approach:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\tag {1} ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx=0 \\
\tag {2} a_1x^2+2h_1xy+b_1y^2+2g_1x=0
\end{eqnarray}$$

From equation (2),

$$2x=\frac {a_1x^2+2h_1xy+b_1y^2}{g_1}$$

I could not move on from here. Please help me to continue.

Comment: A good first step looks to be eliminating $xy$ from one of the equations. I.e use the second equation to replace $xy$ in the first equation.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi, After doing so, I got $$ax^2-\frac {a_1hx^2+b_1hy^2+2g_1hx}{h_1} + by^2+2gx=0$$,

what should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to eliminate the $x$ term from the equations, so that the equation is homogeneous. Multiply the first equation by $g_1$ and the second equation by $g$ and subtract.

You then have $$x^2(g_1a-ga_1)+2xy(g_1h-gh_1)+y^2(g_1b-gb_1)=0$$

The gradient from the origin to $(x,y)$ is $\frac yx=m$ so we divide by $x^2$ and write this equation as a quadratic in $m$.

For the perpendicularity condition we require the product of the roots to be $-1$, so putting that in terms of the coefficients, we get $$\frac{g_1a-ga_1}{g_1b-gb_1}=-1$$

This leads immediately to the result you are looking for.

I hope this helps

Comment: Do we need to subtract second from first after multiplication?

Comment: Can we directly replace $\frac {y}{x}$ with $m$ without giving any reason?

Comment: Yes you need to get rid of the $x$ term. and yes it should be clear why we are using $m$.

Comment: Could.you.please give me the exact reason so that I.could use $m$ in place of $\frac {y}{x}$?

Comment: Its just a substitution if you like! But it represents the gradient of the line. Use another letter if you prefer.

Comment: If I use another letter then again I.had to use it for the perpendicularity condition.

Moreover, I could not understand the perpendicularity condition. How did you get that?

Comment: $m_1\bot m_2\iff m_1m_2=-1$